# How do i compare a Long variable to null

Tags: java, long-integer, primes, bufferedreader, filereader

So im making a txt file reader, and the file has a bunch of "long" lines, because it is a prime number finder program, and it writes the numbers to the txt. when i stop the program, and then restart it, i want it to start where it left off. that means that i have to have it check each line and make sure that it is reading something, and the buffered reader is listed as long. here is the code:

```
try{
        FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(fileLocation);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);

        long stringRead = bufferedReader.read();

        while (stringRead != null)
        {
            stringRead = bufferedReader.read();
            currentNum =  stringRead;
        }

        bufferedReader.close();
        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException filenotfoundexxeption){
            System.out.print("file does not exist");
        }
        catch(IOException ioexception){
            ioexception.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

so the problem is that it doesn't like the `stringRead != null`, and i dont know how to do it otherwise. im a noob, and so please answer using the code already listed. Thanks!

Comment: How does this work in your code without parsing to `long` `long stringRead = bufferedReader.read();`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should probably be doing

```
String line;
while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
{
    currentNum = Long.parseLong(line);
}
```

As `readLine()` will return null when the end of file is reached.

Comment: Meh, `Scanner` provides a simpler API for this task.

Comment: Just for enlightenment, as Matt Ball said, check out [`Scanner`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html), too. This is a paste directly from the class Javadoc:       `Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("myNumbers"));
      while (sc.hasNextLong()) {
          long aLong = sc.nextLong();
      }`

Answer (score 2):

A `long` is a primitive type, so it cannot be `null`. On the other hand, a [`Long`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html) is a reference type, so it *can* be `null`.

Either way, [`BufferedReader#read()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#read%28%29) returns an `int` representing a **single character,** not an entire line. You should use [`#readLine()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine%28%29) combined with [`Long#parseLong()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#parseLong%28java.lang.String%29),

Think about using a [`Scanner`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) instead, which will significantly simplify your code.

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File(fileLocation));

while (scanner.hasNextLong())
{
    currentNum = scanner.nextLong();
}
```

Comment: That's not gonna help him. The `read` method returns a primitive. He needs to do something else.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik true this. Edited.

Answer (score 0):

A long can't be null, it is either 0 (not initialised, or has been assigned 0) or not. You probably want to use the `readLine` method and parse the result to a long using `Long.parseLong()`, rather than reading each character with `read`.

Answer (score 0):

`long` is a [primitive datatype](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html), which cant be null. if its not initialized its `0` . However you can use the `Long` wrapper class. For example `Long stringRead = new Long(bufferedReader.read());`. In your case however that would never be the case, because `read()` never returns `null`, just `-1` if its the end of the file. So your check should be `while(stringRead!=-1)`

Answer (score 0):

You have one number per line? You have to read with `readLine`, that's going to give you the line as a String. Then parse that with `Long.parseLong`. And you can check that the string you get from `readLine` is not null.

Answer (score 0):

According to [the official documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#read%28%29) BufferedReader#read returns int.

> The character read, as an integer in the range 0 to 65535
>   (0x00-0xffff), or -1 if the end of the stream has been reached

Which means that you can check if the returned is not equals to -1.

Answer (score 0):

long is a primitive so it can not be null and also BufferedReader.read returns int so you can simply make it work by change this line

```
long stringRead = bufferedReader.read();
```

to

```
Integer stringRead = bufferedReader.read();
```

or

```
 Long stringRead = new Long(bufferedReader.read());
```

Java 1.5 and above automatically wrap int to Integer.